# How to sum two specific dates in Java

Tags: java, date, sum

How can I add two dates in Java

Example :The sum of  "2020-05-06 13:10:00" and "0000-00-00 01:10:00" would result in "2020-05-06 14:20:00"

I try something like this but it doesn't work :

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Adding dates simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with @AndyTurner. I cannot think of a use case unless you are doing it just for fun.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry, I would like to add for example 10 minutes to a specific hour. So, I have an hour : 14:20. That + 10 minutes = what I want.
I put a date because today at 23:59 + 10 minutes = tomorrow 00.09.

Comment: Have a look at `java.time` package, `java.util.Date` is deprecated.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever post screenshots of text. You might as well pull out your cell phone, take a picture with that while you're shaking your hand (to ensure it's nice and blurry), then upload that to SO.

Comment: You can do that with Calendar (if your using oldschoold java Date) or with LocalDate but as others said - pretty useless. Also there is no Date "00.00.0000".

Comment: Yes, you were clear enough, you want to add a `Period` to a `LocalDateTime`. Please use the `java.time` API.

Comment: @S.B That was pretty clear, but 10 minutes is not a date, it is a period. Summing two dates is a non-sense, do you know how to sum two birthdays? What is 13 February + 12 May?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès um...no...java.util.Date is not deprecated. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date`. Ever.

Comment: @searchengine27 ok 25 out of 30 methods are and 4 out of 6 constructors. Yes you can use Date (which is not a deprecated class) for backward compatibility, but I would never recommend it in any other case.

Comment: As others have said, 0000-00-00 01:10:00 is not a date. Of course we can add *a duration* of 1 hour 10 minutes to a date and time. Please put your question in a way that makes sense, and it will be easier for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, use the new API. For seconds, represent a concept with the right type.

For example, `java.util.Date` represents moments in time (and not dates; it is very badly named). It certainly does not represent the notion of '10 minutes'.

In the proper (new) API, a moment in time expressed in human terms would be `ZonedDateTime`. The notion of **10 minutes** would be a `Duration` (durations have a set amount of time. periods are more vague; a month has variable duration and is thus a period; 10 minutes is always the same amount of time and is thus a duration).

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(10);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-06 13:10:00", dtf);
```

Note that your input time has no timezone and no location included in it. Therefore, `LocalDateTime` is the proper type to represent it.

But that's a problem: LDTs don't really let you add or remove periods/durations. For example in amsterdam, adding an hour to the time '2020-03-29 01:30:00' would result in... '2020-03-29 03:30:00' - yes, that SEEMS like 2 hours, but only 1 hour has passed. That was the exact point in time when the clocks were turned forward an hour. That shows why it is not possible to add or remove units of time without putting it in the context of a timezone we're in.

Thus, you can't do what you want here; you'd have to 'localize' it first. Let's continue:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
ZonedDateTime modified = zdt.plus(d);
System.out.println(dtf.format(modified));
```

and this prints `2020-05-06 13:20:00` as you wanted.

Comment: Note that you _can_ work with `LocalDateTime` and add `Duration` to it (it has a `plus` method as well). Which can makes sense if you want to work with time that is not tied to a timezone, like just the concept of dates and times. This rarely makes sense, but there are applications.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the second string into it numerical parts using regex, and add to the date/time value of the first string.

Like this:

```
public static LocalDateTime add(LocalDateTime datetime, String interval) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(interval);
    if (! m.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid interval: " + interval);
    Period period = Period.of(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)),
                              Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)),
                              Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));
    int seconds = (Integer.parseInt(m.group(4)) * 60 +
                   Integer.parseInt(m.group(5))) * 60 +
                  Integer.parseInt(m.group(6));
    return datetime.plus(period).plusSeconds(seconds);
}
```

*Test*

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-06 13:10:00", fmt);
System.out.println(add(datetime, "0000-00-00 01:10:00").format(fmt));
```

*Output*

```
2020-05-06 14:20:00
```